# Same email ID, multiple mathoverflow,net IDs

Tags: support, login

I had an ID on mathoverflow, stackexchange, which changed without my knowing. I used the anonymous way to answer/question, ie with just my email ID. So now I have two user IDs with the same email address, is it possible to rectify this? I mean consolidate the IDs into one ID, thanks in anticipation!

Comment: File a request with the relevant info here: http://mathoverflow.net/contact